# Applying a Group Policy to a site

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have several sites in Sites and Services in a domain running a number of 2012 servers.
I was wondering how to get a group  policy to apply to a site. 
I tried putting the "test" group policy on a site in Group Policy as seen in the image below but I'm not seeing apply. I ran gpresult but still not seeing it.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?
 [image]

Ideally I'd use this for printers, so that if a user travels to another office the printers in that office would apply. I was considering to do it by IP address but thought this may be easier.

I believe I have added all the subnets and that kind of info to the sites and appears to be working properly as users get the closest login server available to them.

Update: I ran RSOP and it doesn't show it either. 
I checked my sites and services and everything appears correct in that.

Comment: It looks correctly linked. Are you sure your test machine is correctly associating to your site?

Comment: Did you run `gpupdate` before you ran `gpresult`?

Comment: Yes, I tried a gpupdate /force and then ran the gpresult I'm getting other policies that are applied directly to the OU.

Comment: Is your computer associated with the site the GPO is linked to? Run nltest.exe with the dsgetdc switch to verify. Also in rsop.msc, you can view all GPOs with filtering status to see if it is applied but filtered out.

Comment: The user that was logging in had a block inheritance on the OU. When another user logged in this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that was logging in had a block inheritance on the OU. When another user logged in this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using WMI filtering on a computer policy which maps the desired printer.

Create a WMI filter (right click "WMI Filters" in Group Policy Management).

Using the "root\CIMv2" Namespace use the following query (update the default gateway value to match your site):

```
Select * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable
WHERE (NextHop='192.168.0.1')
```

On the "Scope" tab of the GPO apply the newly created WMI filter.

Another way to do this would be a login script which maps printers for the user based on the current IP but I prefer to only use scripts as a last resort.